# limit to number of conditions in a while loop?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

I want to use a while loop with many conditions, like 30+ conditions, my question is, is there a limit to how many conditions I can put into a while loop, or for that matter an if statement or any other conditional?

Comment: When you combine all the single conditions you end up with one expression. I wouldn't recommend it though as depending on the sub-expression there might be more time used to calculate this mega-condition than in the actual loop body.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem for any C++ compiler. Note that the C++03 standard requires compilers to support at least 256 level of nested parenthesized expressions within a full expression (not that it really directly had much to do with your question - other than it sounds to me like an expression that would probably be considerably more complex than yours).  I'm a little curious to see the expression you have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no **technical** limits. Hovever your teammates will most likely cast a damnation upon you having tried to make sense of your code.

The good way is to split your conditions into logical groups and wrap them into functions with self-explanatory names.

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot of sense. This is the solution I think I am going to use. Although the code will only be seen by me, this will make things more logical.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to write that code like this:

```
while (check_if_30_expressions_say_go(input,input2,input3) {
    do_whatevery_you_need_to_do();
}
```

That will hopefully also enable you to further refactor the checking of the 30 expressions into something more sensible.

**Edit**:
*I now see that I do not really answer the question, so for the record:*

You can nest as many conditions into the while loop as you like, but I suggest that for more than a couple of simple expression, you are better of with refactoring them into one or more functions or even objects.

Comment: You did definitely answer the question. Thank you. I up-voted.

Edit: I wasn't aware that I could put a function into a conditional. These are the things they don't teach us in class. I guess I should have figured that on my own but geeze that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there can only be one condition. However, this is enough, with and/ors, which can combine multiple conditions into whatever you want, and there is no limit to this.

```
if (0==a || 56==a) //Technically only one condition
```

It might get confusing, however, if there is a very large number of conditions, you might want to break some of those into smaller groups, if you can, to make your code more readable.

Comment: ok, yeah I meant like 

'code' if(this || that || that || this || another_thing || and_another)

Comment: `56=a`? You've used Yoda conditionals, which is usually not considered good, but *still* cocked it up.

Comment: Ooops. That's why I try to put the numbers first, to make sure I get a compile time error if I do such a typo...

Comment: @DeadMG: isn't that the whole point of the Yoda? If you never cock it up, write it around the sensible way you can.